# App Crash at Launch (Material Theme issue)

Tags: android, crash, material-design, launch

I'm actually creating an app an I would like to use Material Theme Light.

So I put the line `android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Material.light"` 
on the manifest and no errors are displayed.

However when launching the app on my phone it crashes at launch although no errors are displayed in my xml/java sources.

I'm sure this line is the cause, because when I change the manifest to `@style/AppTheme`, it works and lauches.

It's driving me crazy, I need your help please.

Comment: You should show us logs in your phone or hints, does app miss run time permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your activity, What does your activity extend from? If it extends from AppCompatActivity you can't set material theme.

you should set AppTheme as your theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

and in style file, set AppCompat Theme as your parent:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah it extends from AppCompatActivity,  so how am I supposed to gix this?

Comment: Already tried,  it works my app lauch but no material theme,  how can I solve this,  I just want to use Material Theme Light on my app

Comment: I have edited my answer. see and let me know your problem solved or not.

Comment: For more information, you can see [Theming with AppCompat](https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work click on values in resources than open styles.xml file and change this 

with  following 
i was getting the same issue and it is due to the update in the material lib